# Aptana Studio 3 - Rails project won't import

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, aptana, aptana3

I recently had a project which got corrupted, so i reverted to the older version i had in my git repo. Now for whatever reason, I can't import my project into aptana studio3.

The error is:

"No projects are found to import"

I'm assuming it can't find the .project file. This is a functioning project which i can run via command line.

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

go to

> New > Rails Project, uncheck use default location, point it to the
>   root folder of the project using the Browse button, and make sure that
>   the option to generate code is set to "I'll generate my own"

hope it will works

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer - I found that the import was of the wrong type. I was using "Import>Existing Project into workspace" when it needed to be "Import>Existing folder as new project"